# Convergence test of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty ne^{-n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

What convergence test should I use for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty ne^{-n^2}$ ?

Comment: The integral test would do rather nicely, with the obvious substitution $t=x^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a plethora of choices. The Root Test will work quickly, the Ratio Test will work, the Integral Test will work, the Limit Comparison Test will work.

For example, $(ne^{-n^2})^{1/n}=n^{1/n}e^{-n}$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/n}=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}=0$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}=0$, so by the Root Test the series $\sum a_n$ converges.  Indeed $\sum a_nx^n$ converges for all $x$.

**Remark:** Basic Comparison will also do it. By the Taylor series for $e^{n^2}$ we have $e^{n^2}\ge \frac{n^4}{2!}$. So the $n$-th term is $\le \frac{2n}{n^4}$. I prefer this approach, since it confronts directly the "size" of $ne^{-n^2}$.

Comment: Yes I know, but for the limit comparison which serie should I use?

Comment: You can use $\sum e^{-n}$. Root Test or Integral Test are the fastest. The terms go to $0$ very fast, which is why we have so many choices.

Comment: @DavideR $\frac1{n^2}$ will do.